# How do I debug max_allowed_packet going to -1?

Tags: mysql, aws-aurora

I am using Amazon's MySQL Aurora and using JDBI on the client side. Every once in a while, the connection goes bad and I get errors like this -

```
com.mysql.jdbc.PacketTooBigException: Packet for query is too large (70 > -1). 
You can change this value on the server by setting the 'max_allowed_packet' variable.
```

That -1 feels suspicious and seems like an integer overflow or something. Since I have multiple servers and only one of them randomly sees this, I am guessing this has something do with client-side mysql. The error is too fleeting to be able to debug. Any ideas on why this could be happening?

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'max_allowed_packet';`

Answer (score 0):

max_allowd_packet= set to the size of the largest packet requesting; Usually it can set it to 32M and increase it according to ur application needs. Specify it in [mysqld] and client sections in my.cnf For example

```
[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=128M

[client]
max_allowed_packet=128M
```